# Testing with Jasmine a method that fires an async request

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm trying to use Jasmine to test asynchronous methods.

I have something like this:

```
function change(obj) {
  setTimeout(function() { obj.value = 1 }, 500);
}
```

In my test:

```
it('should change the value', function(done) {
  ....
  obj.value = 0;
  change(obj);
  done();

  obj.value.should.equal(1)
 }
```

How can I get it work?

UPDATE: It works like this now, but it messes with some other tests that worked before, should I reset something after the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call done using setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function(){
  done();
}, 1000);
```